# How to emit a custom event from an object in ES6 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

I have a custom object, and I would like to be able to emit and listen to a custom event.

Something like the following simple example:

```
class My_Obj{
    constructor(){
        this.val = 7;
    }

    doSomething(){
        if (this.val <= 0){
            //Emit "done" event
        }
        else{
            this.val--;
        }
    }
}

/* Somewhere else in the code */

let newObj = new My_Obj();
newObj.addEventListener('done', ()=>{console.log("Finished")});
```

Most examples I see use NodeJs, JQuery, or aren't using objects and classes. I know that there is a way to create `let myEvent = new Event('done')` but I'm not sure where to put that when using a class.

Comment: Either implement a callback mechanism yourself or use one of the many event emitter libraries.

Comment: "*I know that there is a way to create `let myEvent = new Event('done')`*" - what does `Event` refer to here?

Comment: @Bergi I have no idea, it was just what was said here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: That page is about dispatching (custom) events on DOM elements, not on arbitrary objects. It's not available in nodejs for example.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let event = new Event("Done");

class MyClass {
  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
    this.domObj = document.createElement("div");
  }
  doSmth() {
    if (this.x <= 0) {
      this.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else {
      this.x++;
    }
  }
  addEventListener(listenerName, cb) {
    this.domObj.addEventListener(listenerName, cb);
  }
  dispatchEvent(event) {
    this.domObj.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}

let e = new MyClass(10);

e.addEventListener("Done", function() {
  console.log(1);
});

e.x = 0;
e.doSmth();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. No errors or anything, but my callback doesn't run. If I'm importing the class from another file will that affect things?

Comment: It's hard to answer because I can't see your code, So I'd recommend you to make your own emitter or smth like this because my solution is  quite wrong in this situation